# Creating water from hydrogen and oxygen

Tags: water, safety, hydrogen, equipment, reaction-control

Assuming a scientist has two canisters: One with a liter of pure gas of hydrogen (single atoms gas), and one with half a liter of pure gas of oxygen (single atoms gas).

The scientist desires to conjunct the two single atom gasses inside some instrument somehow, to create water.

I understand that the process of doing so is some kind of explosion.

What are the names of that **reaction** and of the **instrument** in which it should take place?

I ask this after I saw the film "The Martian", in which the protagonist "Mark Watney" created water from separating hydrogen from hydrazine, then burning it with oxygen in extremely low stream of gasses, creating very small amount of water in each step of a process.

[Here is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cN0-xJ59gKI) in which a youtuber seemingly creates water from burning hyrdogen and oxygen (legal note: I ask any reader not to try this without being certified as a chemist from, a internationally known academic center).

---

This question is for general knowledge: To know the name of the reaction and the common instrument for it.

Comment: Hydrogen and oxygen are not "single-atom gases".

Comment: @user9303970 single hydrogen/oxygen atoms are very unstable and don't occur naturally. [Hydrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen) and [oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen) gases are diatomic gases ($\ce{H2}$ and $\ce{O2}$, respectively).

Comment: @user9303970 _Unstable_ here means that the bond dissociation energy in diatomic hydrogen and oxygen is 436 kJ/mol and 498 kJ/mol, respectively. To give you an idea, see also [atomic hydrogen welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_hydrogen_welding).

Comment: What do you want with an actual apparatus and safety instructions for a hypothetical reaction?!? Total nonsense. Burning hydrogen with oxygen is done with a torch, in the same way as the one used for oxy-acetylene welding.

Comment: I didn't ask for "safety instructions" anywhere, and even if I would, calling a good question for general knowledge with different possible benefits to those who will read it is redundant.

Comment: If you want to have clarification about why your question is still closed, please open an issue on [meta.chemistry.se] and tag it with [meta-tag:specific-question].

Comment: I am sad that my edit suggestion was rejected; I myself created this question from the above account that I already abandoned (I no longer use its email and I don't know its password). I think the edit sharpened the question and is plausible.

Comment: @JohnDoea Please contact support about merging your accounts; then you can edit your question as you wish. On a side note: element names are not capitalised; don't use subscript for text which is not a subscript; your edit did not address the reason as of why this question was closed. I support the decision of the reviewers to reject the suggested edit. If you have more questions about the procedure, please open a question on our meta site.

Comment: Hello @Martin-マーチン; I have a comment one thing you wrote: I don't agree with your suggestion not using subscript: From my long experience with StackExchange it is used for smaller text notes; If you suggest using html inline-styling as in `style="font-size: 10px" instead - with that I would agree.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to change the text size. If it is not important, delete it. If it is important, keep it at the same size. I know this is a practice on other sites in the network, but here we generally discourage this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a single atom hydrogen or oxygen gas means having lots of free radicals just waiting to react with their own species, liberating a huge amount of energy within a fraction of a fraction of a fraction of a second. This is very unstable.

Lets say the hydrogen only reacts with oxygen and vice versa, then such a reaction would be possible. In general it is called radical addition or free radical addition when radicals react with each other.

The bond energy of a O-H bond is about 464 kJ/mol.

If we had 1 mol magic $\ce{O.}$ ( the oxygen radical) gas and 2 moles magic $\ce{H.}$ the result would be 1 mol (normal) $\ce{H2O}$ and 928 kJ energy. This is the energy delivered by 221.8 g of TNT.

This reaction should be slow or taking place in an explosion proof container.

If you did the same with ordinary oxygen and hydrogen, the energy liberated would still be high but not as big as with radicals ( the O-O and H-H bond needs energy to be opened).

Comment: So much thanks Legolas ! If I understood you correctly, it will be less energetic, hence a bit less explosive, to create water from dihydrogen+monooxigen? This is the only way to create the water?

Comment: There is no stable monooxygen, you have to say dihydrogen reacts with a half dioxygen.

Comment: There are many ways to create water, all condensation reactions liberate water ( They are extremely common).

Comment: I thought that in the film "Bring Him Home" (with Matt Damon), he actually separated atoms of hydrogen from hydrozine, then mixed with oxygen in low doses, just to make small amount of water each time again.

Comment: This is true, but unfeasible.

Comment: First of all he needs to make the hydrazine react to nitrogen and hydrogen, which is an explosive reaction and then burn the hydrogen.